# vector spaces and linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

let V be the vector space of all polynomials in the variable x with real coefficients.in the

space V:

```
        D(P(X))=P'(x) (the derivative of P(x))

        M(P(x))=xP(x)
```

prove that both D and M are linear transformations such that DM-MD=I(the identity linear map

on V.

Comment: check that both $M$ and $D$ preserve vector space operations, i.e. sum and scalar multiplication

Comment: for $DM-MD=I$ use the Leibniz rule for the derivative of a product: $D(x\cdot f)=D(x)\cdot f+x\cdot D(f)$ and the fact $D(x)=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(D(aP_1(x)+bP_2(x)))=aD(P_1(x))+bD(P_2(x))$$

and

$$(M(aP_1(x)+bP_2(x)))=x(aP_1(x)+bP_2(x)))=x(aP_1(x))+x(bP_2(x))=$$

$$=aM(P_1(x))+ bM(P_1(x))$$

$$(DM-MD)(P(x))=DM(P(x))-MD(P(x))=D(x(P(x)))-M(P^{'}(x))=$$

$$=P(x)-xP^{'}(x)-x(P^{'}(x))=P(x)+xP^{'}(x)-xP^{'}(x)$$
so $\;DM_MD=I\;$